# Simulating x times, and get a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I run this code 1000 times and get a csv file with two columns (l1, l2) and 8 rows (ABCDEFGH), with the frequency of letters appearance in the simulation.

```
import random
l1= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
l2= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
print l1, l2
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, you don't really want to print 1000 pairs of random letters to the console, do you?

Comment: Writing it to a .csv file is an easy step discussed numerous other places.

Comment: Yes. I want to write a code, applying the stuff I'm learning. I'm a beginner. Sometimes I include the full code that I have developed (with effort), sometimes just an example to learn a general process. It is curious that some users criticize when you upload the whole code, and that other users criticize when you upload only a fragment. Anybody can check my shared codes in my profile. Anyway, I really appreciate all the suggestions. Thanks @Rory Daulton

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to learn about random data so I made a brute force solution.
It should give you an idea on the steps required so you can try to make it more pythonic (I know I will be burned at the stake for this answer!)

```
import random
f = open('output.csv','w')

l1 = []
l2 = []

#create 1000 choices for l1 and l2

l = "ABCDEFGH"

for i in range (1000):
    l1.append(random.choice(l))
    l2.append(random.choice(l))

#count the number of times a letter was picked
L1={}
L2={}

for x in l1:
    if x not in L1:
        L1[x] = 1
    else:
        L1[x] += 1

for x in l2:
    if x not in L2:
        L2[x] = 1
    else:
        L2[x] += 1

#format data for output        
f.write((''+','+'l1'+','+'l2'+'\n'))
for x in list(l):
    f.write(x+',')
    val = str(L1[x])
    f.write(val+',')
    val2 = str(L2[x])
    f.write(val2+'\n')

f.close()
```

It opens in excel OK, but I don't know if it will work in pandas or the like.